# jQuery fade main page content (#main) at top as user scrolls down

Tags: jquery, wordpress, fadein, fadeout, scrolltop

Can't find the exact answer for what I need to achieve.

I have a full-width background of an open book. I need all the content in #main div to start fading out 60px from the top of the browser window when the user starts scrolling down and be completely faded at 40px from the top of the browser. Otherwise, the content scrolls off the top of the book background image and spoils the effect.

Of course, the content has to fade back in when the user scrolls back up again.

This is a Wordpress site using JointsWP (Foundation 6) and apart from on the home page there is a topbar menu (it is not sticky) so shouldn't be an issue.

I am currently getting around the problem with a transparent fixed header with height 60px (css below) and overflow: auto on the main content but this is causing problems with setting the fixed (not sticky) footer, and also I think fading the content would be a better way of doing it.

```
#goto-head { 
width: 100%; 
height: 40px; 
position: fixed;
top: 0;
}

#goto-main {
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
overflow: auto;
padding-bottom: 0px; /* or 40px? */
} 

#footer {
clear: both;
height: 40px;
margin-top: -40px; 
}
```

Just in case it has any bearing, this is the footer js. It's only purpose is to keep the footer at the bottom of the window when there is only a small amount of content on the page:

```
jQuery(window).bind("load", function () {
var footer = jQuery("#footer");
var pos = footer.position();
var height = jQuery(window).height();
height = height - pos.top;
height = height - footer.height();
if (height > 0) {
    footer.css({
        'margin-top': height + 'px'
    });
}
});
```

You can see the site [here](http://www.gotoalmanac.com/)

I know the answer involves jQuery scrollTop and fade, but beyond that I'm lost.

Thanks,
Tracy

UPDATE: To clarify. The only reason I have a fixed header is to stop the text from scrolling beyond 40px from the top of the window. If I can get the text (and images) to fade out and back in at the top as the user scrolls down and up, I can remove the fixed header at the top.

UPDATE2: Here are screenshots of the fixed transparent div removed (I have reinstated the fixed transparent div as the site is live). The first shows a normal page with no fixed div or header. all present and correct. The second shows what happens when you scroll down this page: you can see the search box and the text etc goes beyond the top of the book in the background image. Looks bad!

I want that text/content fading before it gets up there.

[image: This shows a normal page with no fixed div or header]
[image: This shows what happens when you scroll down]

Comment: kind of [this](https://jsfiddle.net/iamraviteja/5vnmdLtk/) ?

Comment: Hi, thanks, but not really, no. As that's hiding the header and the content is still scrolling to the top in plain view. The only reason I have a header is stop the content (text) from scrolling above the top of the book image. If you go to the site look at the background image. I want the text to fade as it get's to the top of the book (40px from the top of the browser window).

Comment: Can you show a screenshot for the view you want ?

Comment: Not really as I can't produce a working demo to take a screenshot of. You should be able to see from the site (link on post). It should look like it is now, but instead of the fixed (transparent) div at the top and scrollbar showing from 40px downwards, I want NO fixed header and text and images all in #main div with all the text and content in to fade out at the top from 60px below the top window  as you scroll down the page, instead of the text scrolling up to the top of the window---which it would do without the current fixed header.

Comment: If you look at the site on a mobile (cell) phone, you'll see the fixed header isn't there, and so the text scrolls right to the top of the window. It looks odd because the background of the open book stops around 40px from the top of the window. So I want content of the web page (above the background) to have faded by the time it gets to 40px below the top of the window. Think of a real book, the words don't go beyond the pages. That's all I'm trying to do.

Comment: I am very sorry,but I didn't get you.